# How to populate dropdown list with MongoDB info, between two different models?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Device model in which I already have several devices on which I regularly perform CRUD (works good).

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const DeviceSchema = new Schema({
  inventoryNumber: String,
  deviceDescription: String,
  supplier: String,
  price: String,
  comment: String,
  debits: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Debit",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Device", DeviceSchema);
```

Next, I have a Debit model in which it should have info about the Device model.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const DebitSchema = new Schema({
  debitDate: String,
  devices: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Device",
    },
  ],
  employees: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Employee",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Debit", DebitSchema);
```

When creating a new Debit (using new.ejs), I want to have a dropdown list with data from the Device model within the form (for example: device.deviceDescription).

For example, I have 5 devices (Device) in the database and I want to display them in the dropdown list when creating a new Debit.

So the question is, how to fill the dropdown list with data from Devices, how to connect these two models so that I can see the Devices model from Debits?

I tried iteration but it didn't work. I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The `populate` method from mongoose achieves what you want.

First you will fetch the relevant debit, then you populate its devices, and finally if nothing went wrong, you can access the info of each device.

This is an example from which you can get inspired:

```js
Debit.
  findOne({ debitDate: '2023-11-11' })
  .populate('devices')
  .exec(function (err, debit) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); return; }
    console.log('Description of the 1st device:', debit.devices[0].deviceDescription);
  });
```